# How to create a View something like when down Arrow in Gmail search bar is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I need to create a view like I've shown in the image below using HTML, CSS, JQuery and JavaScript. View may have input, Label, button. I don't want to use any direct third party implementation. I need to implement this on my own.
I'm novice to JavaScript. Help me with this.

[image]

Comment: If I understand what you are asking then, it will be shown when user clicks on the down arrow button in input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume you can handle the  HTML/CSS.

You'll have to implement the on_click event of the drop down arrow button. Keep the div hidden or set the display to none, and when the user clicks on the drop down arrow, set the visibility to visible or display to block.

You can ideally use jQuery fadeIn(), fadeOut() method for that, to get a nice fade in and fade out effect.

If you are completely new to javascript, I'd ask you to go through a tutorial of sorts, to a get a grasp of how it works, and what you can do with it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide < Tutorial